# Can we run Mulesoft Dataweave code in Java?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Is it feasible to run the Mulesoft dataweave script in Java using any open source libraries ? Mulesoft has announced its open source sometime back, but did not given further details of the libraries. https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/dataweave/

Comment: You could also execute commands from Java to dataweave cli.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [here is an example](https://github.com/qureshii/springboot-dataweave) of using dataweave as a maven dependency.

Comment: Is the libraries used in this example are opensource ? Can we use them in production without license ?

Comment: I do not see the licenses published, I used mvn project-info-reports:dependencies.  There was an announcement that dataweave is "open" here https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/dataweave/ and I see a BSD-3 license on the Dataweave CLI.  But not for these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible but the DataWeave libraries have not been published as open source at this time.